# AWS Cloudwatch Alarm status

Tags: alarm, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I have set cloudwatch alarm to trigger SNS mail whenever some keywords are found in cloudwatch logs. (using metric filter)

1. When those keywords are detected, Alarm state gets changed from **insufficient data** to **alarm** & triggers SNS topic
2. Now, to move from Alarm state **alarm** to **insufficient data** it takes time randomly.

Is there any specific way it works, I expect it to come back to Alarm state **insufficient data** immediately after **alarm** state.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What is the configuration of your alarm? Can you show a picture, or describe it? It would be some statistic (eg Average, Sum, Count) of some metric over some period of time.

Comment: **Configuration**: For a lambda log group I have created a metric filter. **Metric**: Cloudwatch alarm has a metric filter which detects specific keywords from cloudwatch logs.

Comment: The alarm would have some statistic (eg Average, Sum, Count) of some metric over some period of time. What are they set to?

Comment: Statistic is Sum and time is 1 minute.

Comment: Well, that means that the alarm would be in the ALARM state if the Sum of the metric count for the past 1 minute exceeds the threshold you requested. If there is _no_ metric sent for a minute, it would return to INSUFFICIENT_DATA.

Comment: Great!! Thank you very much John :) These kind of subtle information is hard to find in documentation.. !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alarm has a metric period of 60 seconds and some evaluation period (let suppose 3; total equal 3 * 60 = 3 mints evaluation window). 
The alarm will be in Alarm state if all the last 3 datapoints at 60 seconds interval are in Alarm State (above the threshold). 
If any 1 in last 3 datapoint is below threshold then the Alarm will transition to OK. 
BUT, if the latest all 3 datapoints are missing (say your metric filter did not match and as a result no metric was pushed), the Alarm waits longer than 3 periods to transition to InsufficientData and this is by design to accommodate network delays or processing delay.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/AlarmThatSendsEmail.html

Comment: Thanks ShamSuf useful info !

Answer (score 0):

Came across the same situation, used a period of 1 min and some x > threshold.

The state changes to Alarm immediately whenever the metric exceeds the threshold. But to change back to OK/ Insufficient data takes 6 mins. This happens only for missing data.

As per AWS Support this is the expected behavior of Cloudwatch Alarms, clear explanation can be found here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=284182

Comment: I understand that this is the behaviour by design. But surely there's a way to get an alert sooner? It seems like a pretty common situation to me - the thing that publishes the metric is broken, so you want to know as soon as that happens?